# I cannot select and copy onclick event "span element" in javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

`select()` function is working with input tag but not with span tag. How to solve it?

```
<span id="selector">paragraph<span>
<script>
  document.getElementById("selector").addEventListner("click", 
  myFunction);

function myFunction(){
  var selectItem = document.getElementById("selector");
  selectItem.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");

  };
 </script>
```

Comment: `addEventListner` isn't spelled correctly. `addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve selecting and copying a span by creating a dummy textarea and then copying the content like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
   <span id="selector">paragraph</span>
    <script>
       
         document.getElementById("selector").addEventListener("click", 
  copyToClipboard);
        
        function copyToClipboard() {
        var text = document.getElementById('selector').innerHTML;
    var dummyElm = document.createElement("textarea");
    document.body.appendChild(dummyElm);
    dummyElm.value = text;
    dummyElm.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(dummyElm);
}
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, the reason is that the correct use of the select () function does not include the span tag, as the MDN site says:

> "The HTMLInputElement.select () method selects all the text in a  element or in an  element that includes a **text field**."

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select)

A correct use in your code would be the following:

```html
<span id="selector1">paragraph<span>
 <input id="to_select" type="text" name="text1" value="paragraph">
 <input id="selector" type="button" value="Selector">
 <script>
   document.getElementById("selector").addEventListener("click", 
   myFunction);

 function myFunction(){
   var selectItem = document.getElementById("to_select");
   selectItem.select();
   document.execCommand("copy");

   };
</script>
```

Additionally, @Jason Aller's comment is correct: "addEventListner isn't spelled correctly"

Answer (score 0):

@gargXImran

Based on your problem, you can try this code

```js
document.getElementById("pwd_spn").addEventListener("click", copy_password);

function copy_password() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("pwd_spn");
    var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textArea.value = copyText.textContent;
    document.body.appendChild(textArea);
    textArea.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    document.getElementById("copyed_text").innerHTML = textArea.value;
    textArea.remove();
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<span id="pwd_spn" class="password-span">Hii How Are You..</span>

<p id="copyed_text"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope above code will be useful for you.

Thank you.